# Overflow word wrap with textContent

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert a long text into HTML via Javascript. Here is my code.

```
  function introStory(){
  var txt = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  txt.setAttribute('style', 'white-space: pre;');
  txt.textContent = ""
  txt.textContent += "\"Kill them all!\"\r\n\r\nThey came without warning. The humans, beasts, and holy hosts attacks my village and family. They slaughtered all my neighbors, killed my mother and my father."
}
```

For CSS:

```
#paragraph{
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
     text-align: left;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     overflow-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

The text inserted into the div named paragraph doesn't break word as I want it to be. It continues to outside of the designated div. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: use `word-break: break-all`

Comment: to paragraph div write `flex-wrap: 'wrap'` in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: pre-line;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) instead of `white-space: pre;`

Stack snippet

```js
function introStory(){
  var txt = document.getElementById("paragraph");
  txt.setAttribute('style', 'white-space: pre-wrap;');
  txt.textContent = ""
  txt.textContent += "\"Kill them all!\"\r\n\r\nThey came without warning. The humans, beasts, and holy hosts attacks my village and family. They slaughtered all my neighbors, killed my mother and my father."
}

introStory();
```

```css
#paragraph{
     overflow: hidden;
     border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
     text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<div id="paragraph"></div>
```